# infinite loop when updating context in react

Tags: reactjs, react-context

struggling with passing some values from a child to global context so i can use around my app.

After some research, I've been trying to update context on componentDidUpdate:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
        this.refs.input.scrollIntoView();

        if (this.state.history !== this.context.globalHistory) {
           console.log(this.state.history);
           console.log(this.context.globalHistory);
         //  this.context.setGlobalHistory(this.state.history);
           console.log(this.context.globalHistory);
        }

   }
```

If I uncomment the line this.context.setGlobalHistory(this.state.history). I get an infinite loop.

I saw some answers saying to use useEffect but I get this error when trying to do so:

```
Line 67:9:  React Hook "useEffect" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

Any ideas how to get around this? Newbie to react so any help is appreciated.

Full code of the component

```
import React, { Component, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as BaseCommands from './commands';
import Bash from './bash';
import Styles from './styles';
import HistoryContext from "./HistoryContext";



const CTRL_CHAR_CODE = 17;
const L_CHAR_CODE = 76;
const C_CHAR_CODE = 67;
const UP_CHAR_CODE = 38;
const DOWN_CHAR_CODE = 40;
const TAB_CHAR_CODE = 9;
const noop = () => {};


export default class Terminal extends Component {

static contextType = HistoryContext;

    constructor({ history, structure, extensions, prefix }) {
        super();
        this.Bash = new Bash(extensions);
        this.ctrlPressed = false;
        this.state = {
            settings: { user: { username: prefix.split('@')[1] } },
            history: history.slice(),
            structure: Object.assign({}, structure),
            cwd: '',
        };
        this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
        this.handleKeyUp = this.handleKeyUp.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.refs.input.focus();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps({ extensions, structure, history }) {
        const updatedState = {};
        if (structure) {
            updatedState.structure = Object.assign({}, structure);
        }
        if (history) {
            updatedState.history = history.slice();
        }
        if (extensions) {
            this.Bash.commands = Object.assign({}, extensions, BaseCommands);
        }
        this.setState(updatedState);
    }

    /*
     * Utilize immutability
     */
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return (this.state !== nextState) || (this.props !== nextProps);
    }

    /*
     * Keep input in view on change
     */
    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.refs.input.scrollIntoView();

        if (this.state.history !== this.context.globalHistory) {
           console.log(this.state.history);
           console.log(this.context.globalHistory);
           console.log('doesnt match');
         //  this.context.setGlobalHistory(this.state.history);
           console.log(this.context.globalHistory);
        }

   }

    /*
     * Forward the input along to the Bash autocompleter. If it works,
     * update the input.
     */
    attemptAutocomplete() {
        const input = this.refs.input.value;
        const suggestion = this.Bash.autocomplete(input, this.state);
        if (suggestion) {
            this.refs.input.value = suggestion;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Handle keydown for special hot keys. The tab key
     * has to be handled on key down to prevent default.
     * @param {Event} evt - the DOM event
     */
    handleKeyDown(evt) {
        if (evt.which === CTRL_CHAR_CODE) {
            this.ctrlPressed = true;
        } else if (evt.which === TAB_CHAR_CODE) {
            // Tab must be on keydown to prevent default
            this.attemptAutocomplete();
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Handle keyup for special hot keys.
     * @param {Event} evt - the DOM event
     *
     * -- Supported hot keys --
     * ctrl + l : clear
     * ctrl + c : cancel current command
     * up - prev command from history
     * down - next command from history
     * tab - autocomplete
     */
    handleKeyUp(evt) {
        if (evt.which === L_CHAR_CODE) {
            if (this.ctrlPressed) {
                this.setState(this.Bash.execute('clear', this.state));
            }
        } else if (evt.which === C_CHAR_CODE) {
            if (this.ctrlPressed) {
                this.refs.input.value = '';
            }
        } else if (evt.which === UP_CHAR_CODE) {
            if (this.Bash.hasPrevCommand()) {
                this.refs.input.value = this.Bash.getPrevCommand();
            }
        } else if (evt.which === DOWN_CHAR_CODE) {
            if (this.Bash.hasNextCommand()) {
                this.refs.input.value = this.Bash.getNextCommand();
            } else {
                this.refs.input.value = '';
            }
        } else if (evt.which === CTRL_CHAR_CODE) {
            this.ctrlPressed = false;
        }
    }


    handleSubmit(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        // Execute command
        const input = evt.target[0].value;
        const newState = this.Bash.execute(input, this.state);
        this.setState(newState);
        this.refs.input.value = '';
        console.log(this.context)
        //const newHist = this.state.history
       // this.context.setGlobalHistory(this.state.history)
         //console.log(newHist)


    }

    renderHistoryItem(style) {
        return (item, key) => {
            const prefix = item.hasOwnProperty('cwd') ? (
                <span style={style.prefix}>{`${this.props.prefix} ~${item.cwd} $`}</span>
            ) : undefined;
            return <div data-test-id={`history-${key}`} key={key} >{prefix}{item.value}</div>;
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { onClose, onExpand, onMinimize, prefix, styles, theme } = this.props;
        const { history, cwd } = this.state;
        const style = Object.assign({}, Styles[theme] || Styles.light, styles);
        //console.log(history)
        //this.context.setGlobalHistory(history)
        return (
            <div className="ReactBash" style={style.ReactBash}>
                <div style={style.header}>
                    <span style={style.redCircle} onClick={onClose}></span>
                    <span style={style.yellowCircle} onClick={onMinimize}></span>
                    <span style={style.greenCircle} onClick={onExpand}></span>
                </div>
                <div style={style.body} onClick={() => this.refs.input.focus()}>
                    {history.map(this.renderHistoryItem(style))}
                    <form onSubmit={evt => this.handleSubmit(evt)} style={style.form} >
                        <span style={style.prefix}>{`${prefix} ~${cwd} $`}</span>
                        <input
                          autoComplete="off"
                          onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
                          onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp}
                          ref="input"
                          style={style.input}
                        />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


Terminal.Themes = {
    LIGHT: 'light',
    DARK: 'dark',
};

Terminal.propTypes = {
    extensions: PropTypes.object,
    history: PropTypes.array,
    onClose: PropTypes.func,
    onExpand: PropTypes.func,
    onMinimize: PropTypes.func,
    prefix: PropTypes.string,
    structure: PropTypes.object,
    styles: PropTypes.object,
    theme: PropTypes.string,
};

Terminal.defaultProps = {
    extensions: {},
    history: [],
    onClose: noop,
    onExpand: noop,
    onMinimize: noop,
    prefix: 'hacker@default',
    structure: {},
    styles: {},
    theme: Terminal.Themes.LIGHT,
};
```

Comment: How did you declare `this.context`? From the above code, I can see that you have a problem with using React hooks in class-based components which is not acceptable in React

Comment: `useEffect` is a React hook only compatible in React function components. Stick to using `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle methods for React class components. You also need to provide a better code example. What is `this.context`? Is it *actually* a React context? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also, why isn't all of your app using the single global history? It's considered anti-pattern to duplicate global state locally.

Comment: You're trying to use hooks with in a class component, but hooks can only be used in a function component.

Comment: can you add code for your whole component

Comment: Added full code for the component. 

I suspect my core issues here are 

1. I don't understand react well. 

2.  I forked this component from github just so I can use history items globally and am trying to avoid changing as much of it as possible. From other posts I've read, if I were building ground up, it would be suggested to implement differently.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this for a while, I think the "correct" answer is to lift up state I am messing with to the parent completely.

I wanted a lazier route since I didnt write the child component, but after tinkering this long, it would have faster to do this surgery from the start.